# Export a single object in Illustrator without the other objects to SVG code

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, icon, export, svg

So I am pretty much desperate by now.

I am a web developer and -designer, but I don't use Illustrator. I just don't need it at all.
The file that I got from the graphic designer contains two artboards with several icons spread all over these. I need to export every single icon as `SVG`.

So I selected every object, clicked <kbd>Object > Artboards > Fit to Selected Art</kbd> and exported that. I was a little worried because the `SVG` Code I got from that was very bloated and had so many paths defined in it, that I couldn't add classes to it without having to fear that I am doing something wrong.

When I opened the exported `svg` to look if I did something wrong, the whole icon, wrapped by the artboard borders was there, with all the other icons below a grey overlay (!!!). So all the other paths were actually in every single `SVG` file.

I tried everything but it just doesn't work. I cant go in 50 files to delete all the code.

Any solutions?

Comment: If each icon is in a separate layer, you could export each layer to a separate file with [this script](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3108385) and then use @daugaard47 method.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure I 100% understand your question, but sounds like you have many icons and only need one...?

- Just create a new document in illustrator.
- Copy over the icon you need.
- Select the icon, then choose File > Document Setup > Edit Artboards
- Then in the top left choose Presets: Fit to selected art. Then save
  as an .svg

If there are other icons/objects in the scene you have to delete them or the .svg will become bloated.

If you have to do this with all you icons it can be a very tedious task. I've been there.

Hope that helps.